# magento _redirect with parameters that have + or /

Tags: magento, url-encoding

seems like a call to

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/myaction',$myargs);
```

does not properly escape the arguments
so if

```
$myargs=array(p1=>'string that has + or / within it')
```

the created URL will be something like:

```
 ..../myaction/?p1/string%20that%20has%20+%20or%20/%20within%20it
```

causing the getParams collection on the action to have 
p1 with value 'string that has   or '  <- plus sign missing and value broken and
' within it' with no value or something similar.

is there any standard way I should handle the arguments before passing them to _redirect ?

Eyal

Comment: @Andrey:
Thanks, I wander why escaping is not the default for redirect.  I got option 1 on my own, and anyway for now I got around this using a session object, But option 2 looks exactly like what I was looking for.
@Anton: Thanks but I know why I need escaping and what needs to be escaped, I was looking for the HOW and not the WHY.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are two standard ways.

1. Pass all your params as route params, but encode them with php urlencode() func:

   `foreach ($myargs as $key => $val) {
       $myargs[$key] = urlencode($val);
   }
   $this->_redirect('*/*/myaction', $myargs);`
2. Pass your params as query params

   `$this->_redirect('*/*/myaction', array('_query', $myargs));`

You'd better take second approach, because your params logically are not route but query parameters. Magento is made with a lot of architecture thinking, so it usually points better ways to do stuff - that's why in your case it's easier to send params using second way.

Notice: _redirect() internally uses Mage_Core_Model_Url, so everything said in this answer is true for all other url-forming routines and all usages of Url model.

Answer (score 1):

refer to http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy and read the section "Reserved characters"