# Magento : How to redirect with some parameter in admin

Tags: php, magento, redirect, controller

Hi i try to redirect in magento from back end module. i use the following query.

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

It was working but my module page will not work without category id in **GET** parameter with in the url.

So i use the following code

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/?category_id='.$category_id);
```

but now this time directly going to the home page. please any one have any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/', array('_query', array('category_id',$category_id));
```

Should do the job, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540289/622945

Comment: That was working fine.. i take the code from the link you provide... thank you brother :)